# url_for with application controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.0 / Ruby 2.0

I'm trying to convert a Rails 2 application for Rails 4.   In the layout file, I had a script to call an action in the application controller (to reload session variables) and then refresh the page when a refresh button in the layout was clicked.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to reference any action in the application controller:

```
<%= url_for(:action => 'refresh_users', :controller => 'application') %>
```

I've tried 'url_for' a few different ways including not specifying the controller.

For every way I've tried, I always get a no-route error ("No route matches {:action=>"refresh_users", :controller=>"application"}")

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var refresh_user_session = function() {
          $.get(
              "<%= url_for(:action => 'refresh_users', :controller => 'application') %>",
                   function(data){
                       alert('You access rights have been re-loaded, the page will now re-load.');
                    location.reload();
                   }
              );
        return false
    }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: usually the application controller is not used for routing! how do you do that in your routes.rb?

Comment: ? It's not routing, it's just javascript calling an action in the application controller that doesn't render anything.  url_for is just there to write out the path to the action for javascript to use.   If that action code is not in the application controller, it would have to exist in every single controller in the app.  In Rails 2.x it just always worked.

Comment: if you don't expose it via routes, how is anything gonna call it?

Comment: the applications controller methods are suppose to be available by default without setting a route in routes.rb.  It worked that way in Rails 2 and I've tried naming a route for it in the routes.rb file of Rails 4 and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have a misunderstanding of rails routing here.

in rails 2 you usually had something like this in your routes `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'` which allows you to call any action on any controller.

this would allow you to define a public method in your `ApplicationController` and, through inheritance, make it accessible to any controller in your application.

i think that this should still work in rails4. since `match` is deprecated and you are doing a `get` request, i would put something like `get ':controller(refresh_users(.:format))'` in the `routes.rb`. this would allow you to call `/XYZ/refresh_users.json` on any controller.

i am wondering though... why would you actually want to have an action in every controller. that is very uncommon!